# ¿Hay modo oscuro para móvil?

Tags: soporte, web-móvil, modo-oscuro

Me cambié a la versión móvil desde mi compu, ya no lo veo con bugs de sobreposiciones... Pero me pregunto, ¿Hay modo oscuro para la versión móvil?

Ahora mismo lo que veo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si es que no hay, ¿Existen planes para esto?

Comment: Esta pregunta iria mucho mejor en [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta corta: Estrictamente hablando de la app para móviles, no.

Posible solución provisional: En el móvil ve al pie de página y haz click en el enlace "Sitio Completo". El sitio completo es *responsivo*.

---

Versión de esta pregunta en Meta SE:
[Is there dark mode for mobile on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366578/289691)

Relacionado

- [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/289691)